# How to know when a new video is uploaded to a Youtube channel?

Tags: iphone, youtube

I am writing a application to show all videos of a Youtube channels.
I want my app keep in update realtime. It mean my app can know when a new video is uploaded to this channel. Do you know any solution (register notifications???)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the youtube apis?
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html

Comment: Yes, I have, but I don't think Youtube aupport notification

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api
This is the data api it should allow you to pull information about a channel.